# Why the onActivityResult function is not getting overridden?

Tags: android, kotlin

[Modifier 'override' is not applicable to 'local function'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToStp.png)

I have tried checking every opening and closing braces and also restarted Android Studio.

Comment: You are writing this method inside another method . Move it inside class body .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

move your method below closing bracket of `onCreate` call

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    ... current code
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    ... new code
}

private fun generateSampleData(): List<UserMap> {
    ... rest of current code
```

this method belongs to whole class extending `Activity` not "local function", as on the screenshot you are placing it inside another overriden method

btw. `onActivityResult` is deprecated now, you should move to [new approach](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result)